# Insert react component dynamically using class name

Tags: reactjs

Given an array of react class names, I want to create a component using that class name.

I tried:

```
React.createElement(name);
```

But got an HTML element with name (ex: `<MyReactClass/>`), but not an actual react component which is what I need.

Comment: You have to resolve the name to the actual class. You can do this by building a `name -> class` map and look up the class.

Answer (score 3):

You need to map the names to the actual classes, like as @Felix Kling mentioned. The are several ways to do this. One such way:

```
var classes = {
  "name1": require('./Class1'),
  "name2": require('./Class2'),
  ...
};

...
React.createElement(classes[name]);
```